# Bootstrap: div with overflow's internal divs only render border on initial view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3

I have a parent div that will have a variable width, and needs to scroll horizontally. Its css:

```
.div-container{
    overflow: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

Inside that div are several rows of divs, each one being the full width of the container:

```
.div_row{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
}
```

The html structure might look like this, but with dozens of rows and potentially hundreds of boxes:

```
<div class='div-container'>
    <div class='div_row'>
        <div>box 1</div>
        <div>box 2</div>
        <div>box 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is the `div_row` only expands the width of the initial visible portion of `div-container`.[image]

In the image I have scrolled to the right some and you can see the border stops where the rendering of the `div-row` stops, which is the width of the initial visible portion of `div-container`. If I hard code the width of the `div-row` to be 5000px or some other arbitrary large number the border works, but the width is variable and can't be hard coded.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to move the `white-space: nowrap` from the `.div-container` to the `.div-row` and to add `display: inline-block` to the `.div-row` to make it grow based on its contents, see the example below.

However as this looks like a table, why not simply make it a `<table>`?

```css
.div-container {
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #f99;
}
.div-row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9f9;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="div-container">
        <div class="div-row">
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="div-row">
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

Looking into the live example noted in the comments below the following steps should solve the problem.

- Remove `white-space: nowrap` from `.table-container`
- Add `white-space: nowrap` and `display: inline-block` to `.top-row`
- Add `display: inline-block` to `.table_row`

The basic idea is to set `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap` to the rows, forcing them to expand their width based on their contents. The `white-space: nowrap` needed to be removed from their container, `.table-container`, as otherwise due to the rows having `display: inline-block` they would appear on a single line.

Comment: Thanks, I think bootstrap is the root of the problem. While your solution works in plain html, with bootstrap the output is the same as my original code. I am not making this a table because there are a lot of features around sorting and dragging / dropping cells that would structurally be a lot more challenging with a <table>

Comment: Only adding Bootstrap's stylesheet doesn't make the example break, nor does adding a simple grid structure. It could very well be due to another bootstrap element on the page. If you can perhaps add a larger code snippet to your question someone might be able to resolve it.

Comment: Cool, here is a sample of the page, notice whatever size (large, medium, small, etc.) bootstrap params say the window is, that's the size of the row (and consequently the border-bottom) [http://lexilereport.com/test.html](http://lexilereport.com/test.html)

Comment: Try doing the following: Remove `white-space: nowrap` from `.table-container`. Add `white-space: nowrap` and `display: inline-block` to `.top-row`. Add ‘display: inline-block` to `.table_row`. Tested on Chrome by the way.

Comment: Genius! Worked wonderfully.If you want to add that as an answer so you can get the rep points would be happy to check it off. Really clever solution. Thanks

Comment: I've added the solution to this question and added an explanation on why it works.